# Multilang routes with React Router V4 and redirects

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, react-redux, react-router-v4, react-router-redux

So I have a React app which is using Redux and I need to set up I18n on it. I decided to use the [react-redux-i18n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux-i18n) package (not sure that's the best idea, but the alternatives like yahoo's `react-intl` or even `react-intl-redux` seem to be way too complicated). The initial setup went smoothly, but now I got into a roadblock.

I want to pass the locale as a part of the requested URL. E.g. `/en/` for root path, `/en/forums` for forums, etc. Which means that for every path I need 3 routes:

- `/en/:path` for the English (default) locale
- `/ru/:path` for the Russian one
- `/:path` to be a `<Redirect>` to the default locale

Writing 3 routes for every path seems way too dirty and uncomfortable so I decided to make a reusable component for it:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import LayoutRoute from './LayoutRoute';
import appConfig from './config/appConfig';

class I18nRoute extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { path, ...rest } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <Redirect from={path} to={`/${appConfig.DEFAULT_LOCALE}${path}`}/>
                <LayoutRoute exact path={`/en?${path}`} lang='en' {...rest} />
                <LayoutRoute exact path={`/ru?${path}`} lang='ru' {...rest} />
            </div>
        )
    }
};

export default I18nRoute;
```

and then tried using it in my router setup

```
<Switch>
                <I18nRoute exact path="/" layout={MainLayout} component={Home} />
                <I18nRoute exact path="/forums" layout={MainLayout} component={ForumsRoot} />
                <I18nRoute exact path="/forums/:id" layout={MainLayout} component={Forum} />
                <I18nRoute exact path="/topics/:id" layout={MainLayout} component={Topic} />
                <I18nRoute exact path="/users/:id" layout={MainLayout} component={UsersPage} />
</Switch>
```

That backfired in two ways:

1. It doesn't recognize the locale paths, even `/en/` leads to route not found.
2. It doesn't redirect with params in, e.g. `/forums/18` gets patched to `/en/forums/:id`.

is there some fix to this or do I need to go a completely different route? (pun intended)

**UPD**
After carefully writing this down I realized that the redirect rule could be simplified to a regex (if the route does not match /^/(en|ru)/(.*)$/ then redirect to the `/en/:path`).